# Swapping a node function error (C6011: Dereferencing NULL pointer) [ C++]

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list

I made this function so I can do a swap between 2 nodes for my linked list. However, I found this bug in my code that is making my program crash completely. At first, I did not initialize tempNode1 so it gave me a warning. I initialized it to NULL and now it is giving this C6011 dereferencing NULL pointer warning. I compiled anyway despite the warning and the program crashes. I've ran the debugger and it will run until it finally reaches the tempNode1 declaration line. I'm not sure where I'm going wrong in my code:

```
void Records::swapNodes(node* node1, node* node2) {

node* tempNode1 = nullptr;

tempNode1->ID = node1->ID;
tempNode1->first = node1->first;
tempNode1->last = node1->last;
tempNode1->DOB = node1->DOB;
tempNode1->GPA = node1->GPA;

node1->ID = node2->ID;
node1->first = node2->first;
node1->last = node2->last;
node1->DOB = node2->DOB;
node1->GPA = node2->GPA;

node2->ID = tempNode1->ID;
node2->first = tempNode1->first;
node2->last = tempNode1->last;
node2->DOB = tempNode1->DOB;
node2->GPA = tempNode1->GPA;

}
```

Any feedback would be highly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with `nullptr->ID = node1->ID;`?

Comment: `node* tempNode1 = nullptr; tempNode1->ID = node1->ID;` -- Well, the obvious problem is at the very beginning, you're accessing a null pointer.

Answer (score -1):

I wonder if you created a new instance instead of just create a node* temp.

Ex.
node* temp = new node;

temp->info_1;
temp->info_2;
...
Then swap data;

delete temp;

Hope this helps.

Comment: Why use `new` and `delete` for an object that is supposed to be destroyed at the end of the scope in which it was constructed? Also, what are "info_1" and "info_2"?

Comment: I suggest this as a way to easily hold all the information necessary while other information gets swapped. The OP is asking about a swap function with node. The first thing that happened was a dereference of a nullptr which is trying to access memory not technically available to the user. So creating a temporary node, store all the info, swap desired info then just delete the dynamically allocated node. The info_1 info_2 are just generic names. That’s why there was a ‘... ‘after them it was providing a pseudo esc code.

Comment: I see what you are doing. My question is why. Why start with `node * temp = new node;` and mess with dynamic memory allocation instead of using the simpler `node temp;`?

Comment: This may be a great learning experience for me too, but I figured he’s creating a single pointer and trying to hold several bits of information with that single pointer. So I’m doing a “one-to-one” swap. Why? Because as soon as the temp is dereferenced the attempt to write to memory without perform happens. With my thought, this way the swap can happen and then be freed. Am I missing something?

Comment: You missed the other side of the question. Why not `node temp;` instead?

Comment: Well that’s not a pointer what you have there. Node* temp is just a standard pointer, from my understanding will not be able to hold enough information for the information to be swapped. A single pointer only points to one address at a time. Now if it can point to an entire node struct object, information gets swapped then take what node* temp was pointing to then transfer info then great. I was unsure if temp would “hold”  the info of node1 after it was transferred. If you’d help me learn I’m sure OP would appreciate it too. I appreciate you helping to find understanding of “why”

Comment: *"Well that’s not a pointer what you have there."* -- Exactly. A pointer involves extra overhead, both at runtime and at programming time. So don't use a pointer when there is no benefit. Data can be transferred to a local object; there is no need to use a dynamically allocated object.

Comment: Example: `node temp; temp.ID = node1->ID; temp.first = node1->first; // etc.` This accomplishes the same task without the overhead of dynamic allocations, and without the need to remember to `delete` the object at the end of the function. Win-win.

Answer (score -2):

The reason why your program is crashing is because with the line `tempNode1->ID = node1->ID`, you are attempting to dereference `tempNode` (the statement `tempNode1->ID` is equivalent to `(*tempNode1).ID`). The act of trying to dereference `tempNode1` when it is `nullptr` is what is causing the crash. You can avoid this by setting `tempNode` to point to a temporary non-null value before using it for the swap e.g. `tempNode1 = &node()`.

Comment: You've exchanged de-referencing a null pointer for de-referencing a dangling pointer. That's mostly a lateral move with regards to fixing the bug.